# Only output events for a condition when at least a single event matching the condition has been found, else output the input

Tags: azure, azure-stream-analytics

My input has a field 'condition' with only two values. Lets assume only values 'A' or 'B'.

When at least a single event with condition=A within a tumbling window is found, only events with condition=A should be outputted. However, when no events for A are found, only events with B should be outputted in the same window.
Given the following input with a tumbling window of 4 ticks:

```
  Condition   Time  
 ----------- ------ 
  A           T1    
  B           T2    
  A           T3    
  B           T5    
  B           T6    
  B           T7    
  B           T8    
  B           T10   
  A           T11   
  A           T12   
  A           T13   
  A           T14   
  A           T15
```

The output should be as follows:

```
  Condition   Time   (Window)  
 ----------- ------ ---------- 
  A           T1     T1-3      
  A           T3     T1-3      
  B           T5     T5-8      
  B           T6     T5-8      
  B           T7     T5-8      
  B           T8     T5-8      
  A           T11    T9-12     
  A           T12    T9-12     
  A           T13    T13-16    
  A           T14    T13-16    
  A           T15    T13-16
```

How can I setup my steps so the following output is achieved from my input?
I tried several option with using group but was unsuccessful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an interesting problem.
First allow me to correct your definition of a window. Windows of 4 ticks for the time range from 0 to 16 are:

```
( 0 -  4]
( 4 -  8]
( 8 - 12]
(12 - 16]
```

, where start time is excluded and end time is included. The end time is the timestamp of the result of the computation over that window.

Now here is the query that computes your answer.

```
WITH
count_as as (
    SELECT
        cnt = SUM(case cond when 'A' then 1 else 0 end)
    FROM input TIMESTAMP BY time
    GROUP BY tumblingwindow(second, 4)
)

SELECT
    input.cond, input.time
FROM
    count_as a
      JOIN
    input TIMESTAMP BY time
      ON DATEDIFF(second, input, a) >= 0 AND DATEDIFF(second, input, a) < 4
WHERE
    (a.cnt > 0 AND input.cond = 'A')
    OR
    (a.cnt = 0 AND input.cond = 'B')
```

The `count_as` step computes number of A's in a window. This will produce an event at each end of the window (4, 8, 12, and 16 seconds in this example) with the count of A's seen in the last 4 sec.

Then we just join it back with `input`, but only last 4 seconds of it.
And we need to be careful defining time bounds (aka wiggle room) to correctly align with window boundaries. Thus using `>=0 and <4` instead of, say, `between`.

Comment: Very clever trick by using SUM to count the number of the specific condition.